# Xamarin UIStackView before iOS 9

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin with Visual Studio for Mac project going. I decided to build the UI using Xcode and it has been working very well. However when I added a stack view with four views in it, it gave me a "UIStackView before iOS 9" error upon building and running on Xamarin. Xcode is using iOS version 10.2 and Xamarin also. I made sure my simulator is also running 9.0 or above. I can't figure out what else to do! Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Application's `Info.plist` and set the deployment target to 9.0 or above:

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>9.0</string>
```

re: [UIStackView iOS 9.0+ / tvOS 9.0+](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that besides the deployment target of the project, a Storyboard or Xib can also have a specific target set. Which presides the deployment target of the project.

You can set the deployment target in the *XIB document* section in the *Properties* tab when opening a Xib.